# How to target specific ui-view elements when nested ui-views exist

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Imagine some html as follows:

```
<body ng-app="blocksApp">

Some content goes here

<div ui-view="monty">

    <div ui-view="dave">Aaa</div>
    <div ui-view="pete">Bbb</div>
    <div ui-view="steve">Ccc</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Using ui-router, is there any way to code a state that will set "dave" to a new snippet of html, whilst leaving everything else untouched.

e.g. I'd like to do this:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('daveonly',{
            url: "/dave",
            views:{
                'dave':{template:"Dave now has content"}
            }
        })
```

I can't get it to work.  The reason I want to do this is that sometimes I'd like to replace 'Dave' with a partial update, other times I'd like to replace the entire 'monty' with a partial update.  It seems that ui-router does not like having nested ui-views in the same snippet of html.

Comment: your state 'daveonly' should be nested inside the state 'monty' and you should name your dave only view 'dave@monty'

Comment: Like this?:
$stateProvider
        .state('monty',{
            url: "/monty",
            views:{
                '':{template:"Do not need this"}
            }
        })
        .state('monty.daveonly',{
            url: "/dave",
            views:{
                'dave@monty':{template:"Dave now has content"}
            }
        })

Comment: in 'monty.daveonly' you should add parent: 'monty'

Answer (score 3):

From one point of view I'd like to suggest:

- move html code to '.tpl.html' files
- use 'templateUrl' instead of 'template'

And check if the following is suitable for you:

```
$stateProvider.state("daveonly", {
    views: {
        "dave": {
            templateUrl: 'daveonly.tpl.html',
        },
        "pete": {
            templateUrl: 'pete.tpl.html',
        },
        "steve": {
            templateUrl: 'steve.tpl.html',
        },        
    }    
});
```

Take a look at [page1](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view) and [page2](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) for more details.

But from another point of view it could be more useful to use only one ui-view and to redesign current ui-views to become the appropriate directives with controllers/services: usage of directives with controllers/services could help to manage partial reload correctly and to write unit-tests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done easily with the help of abstract states and yes you are correct ui-router doesn't like direct nested views directly but it works fine if the views are in any child template.

Now consider this main page(index.html)

```
<body ng-app="app">
 <div ng-view=""></div>
</body>
```

Now this template which will appear in this unnamed view. (parent.html)

```
<h3>This is the parent template</h3>
<div ng-view="child1"></div>
<div ng-view="child2"></div>
```

Now the JS file

```
$stateProvide.state('home',{
  url:'/',
  abstract:true,
  views:{
    "":{
      templateUrl:'parent.html'
    }
  }
})
.state('home.child',{
  url:"",
  views:{
    'child1@home':{
      templateUrl:'child1.html'
    },
    'child2@home':{
      template:'Child2'
    }
  }
})
.state('home.child.child1',{
  url:"child1@home.child",
  views:{
    'child1@home':{
      templateUrl:'child1viewchange.html'
    }
  }
});
```

(Now the manipulation part)

```
(child1.html)

<button ui-sref="home.child.child1">Child</button>
```

Now child1viewchange.html pe jana padega and wo dekhne wali hai kaunsi kaisi thi/......
    (child1viewchange.html)

```
<h3>Child1's view change</h3>
```

So now when we click on the button in child view1 the content in the first view changes and if we assign controllers then they can use them to control data.

Comment: thanks very much.  I understand that I can do what you suggest, but I specifically want to leverage the initial nested ui-view structure shown in my initial post.  I then want to extrapolate this in a number of directions, targetting ui-views at will without having to force the whole mechanism into lots of 'loads' that only ever inject a single hierarchy of ui-views.  Is that simply not possible?  It seems a big omission from the ui-router capabilities.

Comment: I suppose so too its a big omission! If I come across any developments in this specific issue I'll let you know !!!!